# Laravel - Implementing a data logger with different models/data types

Tags: php, laravel, logging, polymorphism

I want to develop a kind of data logger using Laravel 4.2. There are different kind of sensors in the system with different data formats, for example: a temperature sensor ("TemperatureSensor1") with only temperature data and an energy monitor ("EnergyMonitor1") with energy AND power data (two data columns that belong together).

An external app (running on the server) collects these data and shall post them to the Laravel application using HTTP POST and a route like this: /sensors/TemperatureSensor1/data. The body of this HTTP POST consists of a JSON request, for a temperature sensor this would be {"temperature": 12.3} or in case of the energy monitor this would be {"energy": 10000.3, "power": 123.3}. The Laravel application should store every dataset of every sensor in a MySQL database. I thought about having one table per sensor for storing the data points. In this example:

```
Table "TemperatureSensor1":

id | timestamp | temperature
1  | 123       | 12.3
...

Table "EnergyMonitor1":

id | timestamp | energy  | power
1  | 128       | 10000.3 | 123.3
...
```

There is also a table called "sensors" which looks like this:

```
id | sensor_name        | alias       | data_type
1  | TemperatureSensor1 | Living room | 0
2  | EnergyMonitor1     | House       | 1
```

So the logical path should be:

1. Sensor data collected by external app.
2. HTTP POST to Laravel app /sensors/Sensorname/data with sensor specific JSON data.
3. Laravel app looks in table "sensors" if it exists. Depending on the field "data_type" the JSON data is forwarded to a concrete model, for e.g. data_type=0 --> TemperatureSensorModel or data_type=1 --> EnergyMonitorModel.
   Note: There can be a lot of temperature sensors in the system. All of them have different names and different tables with stored data, but have the "TemperatureSensorModel" in common.
4. The concrete model "decodes" the data and stores them in the sensor-specific table.

Step 3 is somewhat unclear to me at the moment. How would I do this in Laravel? This kind of smells like a polymorphic relation (different behaviour depending on the data_type) but I don't think that the examples fit.

Is there maybe another/better strategy to implement this kind of application?

**EDIT**

To be more clear what I want to do with the data:

By calling /sensors/{Sensorname}/data/view (or something like this), a View should be rendered which should contain a plot of the collected data. Note that for every sensor type, a different view exists because a temperature plot looks different from an energy plot.

The view contains the reference to a JS plotting component which should get the plot data from the database. This could be done by AJAX request of /sensors/{Sensorname}/data which would yield the logged data of table "Sensorname" (e.g. "TemperatureSensor1") in a JSON format.

I experimented a bit and this is what I came with:

I have a resource controller and a nested resource controller, like this:

```
Route::resource('sensors', 'SensorController');
Route::resource('sensors.data', 'SensorDataController');
...

class SensorDataController extends BaseController {

    public function store($id) {
        $sensor = Sensor::where('sensor_id', $id)->first();
        $sensor_model = SensorModelFactory::fromSensor($sensor);

        // do something with $sensor_model
    }
}

class SensorModelFactory
{
    public static function fromSensor($sensor)
    {
            $sensor_model = null;

            if ($sensor)
            {
                    switch ($sensor->data_type)
                    {
                            case TemperatureSensor::DATA_TYPE:
                                    $sensor_model = new \TemperatureSensor;
                    }

                    if ($sensor_model)
                            $sensor_model->setTable($sensor->sensor_id);
            }

            return $sensor_model;
    }
}
```

This seems to do the job for now. I receive a concrete `$sensor_model` from the SensorModelFactory based on the data_type that is stored in the database table "sensors".

Comment: Polymorphic relationship is exactly what you need. It's essentially an audit table that can have many different sensor types all with common data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your example one important issue is how are you going to use the data. Since you didn't exaplain that I will assume that you have no reason to use  /sensors/Sensorname/data, since for each sensor you would need to create a new route.

It seems that the best options would be to keep the restful approach, such as creating a /temperature route where you can have a POST, PUT, DELETE or GET as usual, and you would add a parameter describing from which sensor the data came from. This way you always have the same route and you can have multiple parsers, if you really need that.

Comment: I added some information and a possible approach in my original post. You are right, there is no real reason to use /sensors/Sensorname/data. This is just what I had in mind and would IMHO best fit this use case. Using a different route for every sensor type would duplicate more code (I think). That's why I thought about the SensorModelFactory. Then I only have to add a new concrete model (parser) and update the factory class.

Comment: It still seems strange to me. If you have a scale and you want to store the weight of something I would create the /weight route despite the fact of I'm using a scale to automatically handle that or if I'm adding the data manually. That said, using the sensor as a reference instead of the actual data that you are storing, it seems odd to me. Thus, instead of using /sensors/{Sensorname}/data/view I would use /temperature and /energy to list all the data I would need. But I guess I didn't really get your business needs.

Comment: You are right, using my first approach produces a lot of difficulties in the further development process. The RESTful approach with different routes for every sensor type makes more sense.